# using scanf and printf makes the program infinite loop but by replacing with cin and cout works ok

Tags: c++, c

My problem was to take the inputs until user input the test value 0 and the problem is to be solved only by c language, my code below becomes infinite loop by using **scanf** and **printf** but the same code if written in **C++** it works fine with no problem, Can you help me with my C program what i am missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int click,test=1,count=0;
    char vote;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test){
      int i=0;
      for(int i=0;i<test;i++){
      scanf("%c",&vote);
      scanf("%d",&click);
       printf("%c %d hi \n",vote,click);
}
      scanf("%d",&test);
    }
  //printf("%d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
my test case was
    2
    P 1
    P 2
    2
    P 2
    M -2
    0
```

In c++ my output comes exactly like test case but in c language its **TLE or output limit exceed**

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf()` to see if an error has occurred.   If `scanf()` encounters bad data (e.g. while reading an `int` using the `%d` format) then the bad data is left pending (to be read next time), the variable being read is unchanged, and `scanf()` returns a different value than it would if there was no bad data.   You're doing that in a loop, so .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with C you should always check return values of runtime functions, it is the best way to avoid getting errors like the one you have.

scanf returns the number of items that it managed to parse or 0 if it failed.

personally i prefer to use fgets() to read from the stdin and then sscanf to parse the buffer, that way you have (IMHO) a better control of what comes into the program as opposed to obscure scanf formatting. it is easy to do mistakes with scanf because one tends to forget that all input is buffered and scanf reads from that buffer.

E.g.  (ocular compiled only)

```
int click = 0;
int test = 0;
char buffer[128];
char vote = 0;

do
{
  if ( fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) != NULL)
  {
    // read number of tests
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &test) == 1)
    {
      for(int i=0; i < test; ++i)
      {
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
        {
          if (sscanf( buffer, "%c %d", &vote, &click) == 2)
          {
            printf( "%c %d hi \n", vote, click );
          }
          else
          {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format encountered\n");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
while (test);
```

Comment: i am a college student and started learning coding recently so i want to know are these in depth details of predefined functions are to learned from books or it's the 
 by experience we learn. And Thank You for your answer

Comment: @DeepanshuSingh the runtime is pretty straightforward to learn, it is just a matter of reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/c

Answer (score 0):

The %c conversion specifier poses problem with leading white spaces as it won't automatically skip them.  Since you're receiving inputs in loop, one way to mitigate it is via putting extra space before `%c`.

```
scanf(" %c", &vote);
```